# Offset space following a translated (transformed) element

Tags: html, css

I’ve vertically centred an element on the bottom edge of its parent by using `transform: translateY(50%)`.

The issue I have is when the element is translated down by half of its height, any content after this section isn’t bumped down by the same amount. Of course, all heights are automatic based on content, so I can’t just apply some arbitrary margin/top value to the next section.

This would be really easy to with Javascript, but I’d rather avoid using Javascript to render layout, to avoid having to recalculate if content or the viewport changes.

Here’s the pen: http://codepen.io/danielvdspuy/pen/KMMOMW

---

**Markup (Jade):**

```
header
  .b-hero
    .b-wrapper.b-intro
      .b-welcome 
        h1.b-welcome__heading Supercharge your talent
        p.b-welcome__message We create electrifying content for editorial titles or brands, and provide cutting-edge training courses
        .b-testimonials
          p.b-testimonials__quote “Dashboard Media is the best kept secret in training. The team is always happy to tailor a course to our needs.”
          p.b-testimonials__byline 
            | Jess McAree 
            br 
            | Group Head of Editorial Learning
            br
            | Haymarket Media
  .b-section.b-wrapper
    p You can’t see me, because I’m being covered =(
```

---

**Style (Stylus):**

```
*
  box-sizing         border-box

body
  background-color   rgba(255,255,255,1)
  font-family        sans-serif
  color              white
  line-height        150%

h1
  margin             0 0 0.5em 0
p
  margin             0

header
  background-color   rgba(0,0,0,0.05)
  position           absolute
  top                1em
  right              1em
  bottom             1em
  left               1em

.b-hero
  background-color   rgba(0,0,0,0.1)
  height             15em

.b-wrapper
  position           relative
  height             100%
  margin             0 auto
  max-width          1000px
  display            flex
  align-items        flex-end

.b-welcome, .b-testimonials
  padding            3em

.b-welcome
  background-color   rgb(0,141,62)
  background         linear-gradient(to right,
                     rgb(0,141,62) 0%, 
                     rgb(139,197,63) 100%)
  width              100%
  padding-right      calc(35%+3em)
  transform          translateY(50%)

.b-testimonials
  background-color   rgb(30,30,30)
  width              35%
  position           absolute
  bottom             0
  right              0
```

---

Thanks!

Comment: When I look at your code it is just a big mess, `position: absolute` mixed with `flexbox` mxed with `translate`....  very little chance to guess what it should look like, so could you post an image showing the expected result please.

Comment: @LGSon None of that code is a problem, the question is how to push the section that says ‘You can’t see me, because I’m being covered =(’ down by the same amount as the translate so that you can see it.

Comment: Your "You can't see me" text won't show up if removing the `translateY`, so something else is wrong, and `translateY` shouldn't be needed in the first place to center a simple text, which for me make the code somewhat messy, so for me at least, to assist, I would like to know the expected result, as it is not very easy to imagine as is.

Comment: http://codepen.io/danielvdspuy/pen/QEKxpm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to make this work depends very much on what else should be in that page.

Assuming it is the centered one and the text (which of course can contain images, more text etc.), one can do like this, where the second div is nested inside the centered div, having `position: absolute` to push it to the bottom and grow from there.

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/srvkovxx/)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  font: 21px/24px Courier New;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #0068b3;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.hero {
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: #2f3440;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: end;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-end;
      -ms-flex-align: end;
          align-items: flex-end;
}
.blurb {
  background-color: rgba(254,199,0,0.85);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(50%);
          transform: translateY(50%);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
.pad {
  padding: 20px;
}
.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="hero">
  <div class="blurb wrapper pad">“But we shouldn't use our humility as an excuse for inaction. In Washington, they call this the Ownership Society, but what it really means is - you're on your own. America, now is not the time for small plans. America, we cannot turn back. The United States does not accept the legitimacy of continued Israeli settlements.” —Barack Obama

    <div class="text wrapper pad">Text in this section is now covered by above element. It needs to move down by the same amount so the spacing is correct (prior to adding padding)</div>    
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I guess considering the relative nature of everything, this is pretty much the only solution without javascript. I think I’ll need to decide how I want to lay out my page another way to avoid issues with all these wrapper divs and absolute positioning declarations. Btw, as soon as I saw ‘one can do like this’ I knew you were a Swede   “man kan gör såhär”…

Comment: @DanielvanderSpuy Visst är jag det :) .. and yes, you might find another way without wrappers and absolute positioning, though nothing wrong using them if used wisely ... some things just can't be done without them